# multiprocessing start method "fork" causes python crash on Apple Silicon chip

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, apple-m1

Thank you in advance for anyone able to offer insight.

I'm running Python 3.8.2 with all software installed in a Rosetta-enabled terminal on OSX 11.2.3 on an M1 chip.

I have not figured out a minimal reproducible example that does not include proprietary code, as simply running some basic computations using `set_start_method('fork')` does not reproduce the crash.

I need `'fork'` and not `'spawn'` or `'forkserver'` for performance reasons, my application runs about 10x faster with just `'fork'`.

Other places on the internet have suggested setting env var `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES`, but this does not work for me.

I am just running something in one subprocess because python's gc does not clean things up properly. It's not great, suboptimal, but it's what I have to work with at the moment. Essentially I have something that looks like (for those in the know, this is the same as using the [`processify`](https://gist.github.com/Chiron1991/8199fc1a41c2107982053aba809838c6) decorator).

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
import traceback

mp.set_start_method('fork')

...

def rebuild_data_files(queue, *args):
    try:
        ret = some_big_computation_that_generates_lots_of_state_that_python_gc_does_not_clean_up_properly()
    except Exception:
        ex_type, ex_value, tb = sys.exc_info()
        error = ex_type, ex_value, ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))
        ret = None
    else:
        error = None

    mp_queue.put((ret, error))

def run_service():
    q = mp.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(
        target=rebuild_data_files,
        args=[q] + arg_list,
    )
    p.start()
    ret, error= q.get()
    p.join()
    
    if error:
        ex_type, ex_vlaue, tb_str = error
        message = f'{ex_value} in rebuild_data_files\n{tb_str}'
        raise Exception(ex_type, message)
    count, stats = ret
```

Stacktrace as follows:

```
Process:               Python [57779]
Path:                  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               ???
Build Info:            python3-73040006000000~129
Code Type:             X86-64 (Translated)
Parent Process:        Python [57590]
Responsible:           Terminal [32472]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-04-14 17:04:48.680 -0500
OS Version:            macOS 11.2.3 (20D91)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        84EAE763-C15C-08EA-452F-F64014100B3B

Sleep/Wake UUID:       08BA7C07-F80E-4CBD-936A-68E1AD911EFF

Time Awake Since Boot: 62000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       5400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes:       KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000010cc02a72
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Bus error: 10
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xa
Terminating Process:   exc handler [57779]

VM Regions Near 0x10cc02a72:
    shared memory               10cbfe000-10cc02000    [   16K] r--/r-- SM=SHM  
--> Rosetta Return Stack        10cc02000-10cc03000    [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  
    Rosetta Return Stack        10cc03000-10cc07000    [   16K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Application Specific Information:
*** multi-threaded process forked ***
crashed on child side of fork pre-exec

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff200d656f _os_log_preferences_refresh + 75
1   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff200d6f42 os_log_type_enabled + 604
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20412a24 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyValueForKey:] + 175
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20412954 -[CFPrefsSource copyValueForKey:] + 47
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2041290d __76-[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:]_block_invoke + 32
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2040afdd __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 361
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20563984 -[_CFXPreferences withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 372
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2040aa61 -[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:] + 137
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2040a9a0 _CFPreferencesCopyAppValueWithContainerAndConfiguration + 101
9   com.apple.SystemConfiguration   0x00007fff20dd8e4b SCDynamicStoreCopyProxiesWithOptions + 155
10  _scproxy.cpython-38-darwin.so   0x000000010ec81890 get_proxy_settings + 32
11  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c4b7baf cfunction_vectorcall_NOARGS + 207
12  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
13  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
14  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
15  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
16  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
17  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
18  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
19  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
20  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
21  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
22  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
23  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
24  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
25  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
26  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
27  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
28  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556b9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29753
29  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
30  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
31  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47c14b method_vectorcall + 171
32  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
33  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
34  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
35  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
36  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556b9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29753
37  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
38  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
39  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556b9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29753
40  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
41  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
42  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47c14b method_vectorcall + 171
43  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
44  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
45  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
46  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
47  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47c14b method_vectorcall + 171
48  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
49  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
50  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
51  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
52  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47c14b method_vectorcall + 171
53  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
54  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
55  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
56  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
57  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47c26d method_vectorcall + 461
58  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c479124 PyVectorcall_Call + 100
59  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c555a34 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30644
60  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
61  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
62  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478bb0 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 128
63  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47a2f3 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
64  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c4d2b74 slot_tp_init + 180
65  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c4ce054 type_call + 292
66  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478dd6 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 374
67  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55913c call_function + 652
68  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
69  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
70  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
71  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c479124 PyVectorcall_Call + 100
72  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c555a34 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30644
73  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
74  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
75  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
76  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
77  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
78  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
79  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
80  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
81  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
82  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
83  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
84  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
85  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478bb0 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 128
86  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47a2f3 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
87  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c4d2b74 slot_tp_init + 180
88  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c4ce054 type_call + 292
89  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478dd6 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 374
90  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55913c call_function + 652
91  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
92  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
93  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
94  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
95  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556b9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29753
96  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
97  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
98  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
99  com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556b9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29753
100 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
101 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
102 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c479124 PyVectorcall_Call + 100
103 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c555a34 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30644
104 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
105 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
106 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556b9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29753
107 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
108 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
109 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47c14b method_vectorcall + 171
110 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
111 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
112 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
113 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
114 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556b9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29753
115 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
116 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478c0a _PyObject_FastCallDict + 218
117 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47a2f3 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
118 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c4d2b74 slot_tp_init + 180
119 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c4ce054 type_call + 292
120 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478dd6 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 374
121 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55913c call_function + 652
122 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
123 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
124 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
125 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556d6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29782
126 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
127 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
128 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556d6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29782
129 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
130 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
131 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556b9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29753
132 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
133 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
134 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
135 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
136 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
137 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
138 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
139 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
140 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
141 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
142 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
143 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c479124 PyVectorcall_Call + 100
144 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c555a34 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30644
145 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
146 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
147 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47c26d method_vectorcall + 461
148 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c479124 PyVectorcall_Call + 100
149 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c555a34 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30644
150 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
151 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
152 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c479124 PyVectorcall_Call + 100
153 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c555a34 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30644
154 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
155 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
156 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
157 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
158 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
159 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
160 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
161 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556d6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29782
162 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
163 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47c14b method_vectorcall + 171
164 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
165 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556d6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29782
166 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
167 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
168 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478bb0 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 128
169 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47a2f3 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
170 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c4d1419 slot_tp_call + 169
171 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478dd6 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 374
172 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55913c call_function + 652
173 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
174 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
175 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
176 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556b9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29753
177 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
178 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c479124 PyVectorcall_Call + 100
179 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c555a34 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30644
180 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
181 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
182 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
183 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
184 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
185 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
186 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
187 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556d6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29782
188 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
189 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47c14b method_vectorcall + 171
190 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
191 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556d6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29782
192 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
193 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
194 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478bb0 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 128
195 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47a2f3 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
196 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c4d1419 slot_tp_call + 169
197 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47926b PyObject_Call + 171
198 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c555a34 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30644
199 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
200 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
201 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
202 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
203 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
204 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
205 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47c14b method_vectorcall + 171
206 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
207 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
208 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
209 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
210 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c479124 PyVectorcall_Call + 100
211 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c555a34 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30644
212 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
213 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
214 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
215 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
216 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
217 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
218 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
219 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
220 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
221 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c479124 PyVectorcall_Call + 100
222 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c555a34 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30644
223 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
224 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
225 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
226 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
227 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
228 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
229 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
230 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556d6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29782
231 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
232 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47c14b method_vectorcall + 171
233 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
234 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556d6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29782
235 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
236 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
237 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478bb0 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 128
238 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47a2f3 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
239 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c4d1419 slot_tp_call + 169
240 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478dd6 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 374
241 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55913c call_function + 652
242 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
243 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
244 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c479124 PyVectorcall_Call + 100
245 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c555a34 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30644
246 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
247 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
248 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
249 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
250 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
251 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
252 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
253 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556d6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29782
254 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
255 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47c14b method_vectorcall + 171
256 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
257 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556d6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29782
258 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
259 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
260 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478bb0 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 128
261 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47a2f3 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
262 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c4d1419 slot_tp_call + 169
263 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478dd6 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 374
264 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55913c call_function + 652
265 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
266 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
267 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
268 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
269 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
270 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
271 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
272 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
273 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c479124 PyVectorcall_Call + 100
274 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c555a34 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30644
275 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
276 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
277 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
278 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
279 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
280 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
281 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
282 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556d6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29782
283 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
284 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47c14b method_vectorcall + 171
285 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
286 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5556d6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29782
287 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
288 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47990d _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 253
289 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478bb0 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 128
290 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47a2f3 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
291 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c4d1419 slot_tp_call + 169
292 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c478dd6 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 374
293 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55913c call_function + 652
294 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55584e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30158
295 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c47978d function_code_fastcall + 237
296 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c559012 call_function + 354
297 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55578a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29962
298 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c55a097 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3287
299 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c54e1e0 PyEval_EvalCode + 48
300 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c59f933 PyRun_FileExFlags + 291
301 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c59ed9f PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 271
302 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5be267 Py_RunMain + 2103
303 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5be793 pymain_main + 403
304 com.apple.python3               0x000000010c5be7eb Py_BytesMain + 43
305 libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff20381621 start + 1
```